# Do these sentences for recommending others to search on Google, sound patronizing?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning, expressions, present-perfect

And are they natural? In what situation will you use it?

1. Why not google it?
2. Why don't you google it?
3. I think you can google it.
4. You'd better google it.
5. I'd google it if I were you.

Comment: The problem isn’t the wording, it’s the sentiment. “Go use a search engine (and stop bothering us) isn’t helpful. You could make it less patronizing by making it more helpful. For example, suggest terms they could search for, or ask them why searching Google didn’t help them.

Comment: Thank you, ColleenV. Does it mean it'll always sound rude unless giving him practical suggestions?

Comment: It’s a matter of opinion and context whether it will be perceived by someone as rude. It’s always better to be as helpful as possible though, don’t you agree? Let’s wait to see if someone writes a proper answer. I’m at work so I can’t right this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're telling the person that they should really do now what they should have done already, the advice is always going to sound a little patronizing or critical, unless you suggest that a Google search might not yield helpful results (perhaps because the search terms are very broad, say, or the topic is very recondite):

> You could try to Google it.

Emphasis on *try* not on *could*.  If you put the emphasis on *could*, the tone is sarcastic.